# Help fixing virtual consoles (tty1-6) under VirtualBox

Tags: 11.10, virtualbox, tty, virtual-console

I updated my Ubuntu from 10.4 to 11.10. (Huge mistake, I know.) I am unable to view my virtual consoles ttyS1- ttyS6

This happens inside VirtualBox and gdm is running in the background.

I'm not sure what caused this issue. And I'm not sure why it's persistent.

[image: huge text in small blue window]

That's ttyS1; you can barely see it.

Thanks for your time.

BTW, This problem occurs with fresh install of 11.10 on virtualbox too.

Comment: This [bug](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/9490) is fixed in Virtual Box release 4.1.6. Please install the most recent version([see also here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/41478/how-do-i-install-the-closed-source-version-of-virtualbox/41487#41487)).

Answer (score 1):

1. Upgrade VirtualBox to 4.1.6. using the procedure described in [How do I install VirtualBox 4.1?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66765/how-to-install-virtualbox-4-1-4)
2. Download VirtualBox 4.1.6 Oracle [VM VirtualBox Extension Pack](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.1.6/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.1.6-74713.vbox-extpack) and install it (just double click on the file).
3. Start your virtual machine and open a terminal.
4. Install your VirtualBox Guest Additions.

   ```
   sudo /etc/init.d/vboxadd setup
   ```

   Restart your guest.

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge virtualbox-guest-utils
   ```
5. The guest kernel is updated using the command:

   ```
   sudo /etc/init.d/vboxadd setup
   ```

   Restart your guest.
6. This package provides the X11 guest utilities for VirtualBox. These utilities are meant to be run inside the virtual machine.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-utils
   sudo /etc/init.d/vboxadd setup
   ```

   Restart your guest.
7. Install VirtualBox Guest Additions

   ```
   sudo /etc/init.d/vboxadd setup
   ```

   Restart...

P.S : I recommend do it step by step and test with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>. If something gord wrong just purge the package install in that step do it again. That is how I fixed in my own machine...

[image: virtual console working]