# strange text-mode behavior (large fonts and blue lines) with virtualbox

Tags: 11.10, virtualbox, text-mode

I've just installed Ubuntu 11.10 on Oracle VirtualBox and everything went fine except going to text-mode using CTRL + ALT + F1, the console appears in strange behavior as seen on the following link
http://img443.imageshack.us/img443/1073/textmodeinx.png

I appreciate your help :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Help fixing Virtual Console (tty1-6) under VirtualBox](http://askubuntu.com/questions/72867/help-fixing-virtual-console-tty1-6-under-virtualbox)

Comment: This [bug](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/9490) is fixed in Virtual Box release 4.1.6. Please install the most recent version ([see also here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/41478/how-do-i-install-the-closed-source-version-of-virtualbox/41487#41487)).

Comment: Actually the host is Windows 7 and Ubuntu 11.10 is guest. Although I updated Virtual Box on the host machine to latest version but the problem exists.

Comment: If the problem persists even [after updating guest additions](http://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-virtual-box/22745#22745) you may consider communicating this in the bug report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As  @Takkat Mentioned, this should be fixed in latest Virtual Box version

Comment: I'm having the same problem just now, where it was fine before I shared a Windows folder. I'd freshly installed Ubuntu on VBox latest (Win7 host), ran all 364 updates, seeminlgy set up the folder share with ease, restarted, tested the folder share works.

I've been following these steps here: http://chrisfulstow.com/running-node-js-on-windows-with-virtualbox-and-ubuntu, I'm at the 'install Git' part.

And so after restarting and testing my folder share in the GUI, I ctrl+alt+f1 and get this weird command prompt.