# Switching to console mode in VirtualBox distorts graphics

Tags: virtualbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Help fixing Virtual Console (tty1-6) under VirtualBox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72867/help-fixing-virtual-console-tty1-6-under-virtualbox)

I'm using Virtualbox 4.1.2 on a Windows host, and have ubuntu 11.10 oneiric installed. I can use the graphic mode normally, but when I try to use console model (Ctrl+alt+f1,ctrl+alt+f2) a distorced screen is showed (see the screenshot).

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think you would be best served by installing 'openssh-server' and establish an SSH session into that VM using PuTTY or the Cygwin terminal - you can then run byobu or just straight Tmux or Screen to allow for multiple console applications at one time. It would give you much more flexibility, and be (I think) a good bit faster, and smoother than using VT's in the VirtualBox display.

Answer (score 0):

The virtualbox guest additions only work in X11.  It's by design.  If you want term access use a)remote connection via ssh and Putty or b)accept that without the GUI running you have a set resolution.