# An exe file that I want to run on linux made for windows comes up as a Trojan on VirusTotal - how would I run it without it affecting my system?

Tags: wine, executable, viruses

Is there any way that I can run this program on my Linux system without possibly getting a virus?

Comment: You would have to tell us what virus. It could potentially run in wine, in which case it could "infect" any file your user has rw access to ( most anything in /home/your_user ). If you do not run it (or wine) as root it is unlikely to affect system files.

Comment: Can you tell us exactly what the program is you're trying to run and where you got it from? As bodhi.zaen said, you could simply have a false positive, though it is hard to tell unless we know exactly what you have.

Comment: This is what I'm trying to run: https://www.virustotal.com/file/f9c972b2d60e1ac28563a45f647afee7337f5ff897a51df305b3de2af06da80f/analysis/1327287542/

its a modifier for a custom IOS for the wii - the guy has insisted its not a virus but 3/42 virus scanners said its a trojan

Comment: Great question! :)

Comment: @AlexPoulos The page you linked to looks like it runs the scan across many different antivirus products and displays the results. I've used a similar service in the past (though I can't seem to find its page now). But in general, if you run the file through such a page and only a couple scanners say it is infected, then it's most likely a false positive. If a large portion of them say it is infected (like a third or more), then you should start worrying. Also, it'd be great if you could edit your comment back into your answer, so as to keep things nice and tidy. Thanks!

Comment: @WarriorIng64 thank you for that, but if I wanted to be sure and be absolutely protected, how would I make sure that I wasn't going to be infected by the trojan in a Wine environment?

Comment: @AlexPoulos To that, all I can say is that you *can't* be sure without actually trying it. This is true regardless of any random file or piece of software one gets from the Internet that's not directly from a reputable organization. You could read and compile the source code yourself if it's provided, or set up a test machine with Wine installed and see what the effects are there. But as I said before, I don't think it should be an issue this time around, although that judgment's based on probability.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Be aware please that even tough this *will* work probably fine, running a virus inside any live system is never a good idea, even if you are *sure* that you can revert / eliminate the effects of the virus. For a safer approach the answer from [bodhi.zazen](https://askubuntu.com/a/97744/25863) is recommended. This is the safest steps to run something that is not really safe.

---

Any program running inside a wine prefix has only access to the virtual bottle in that .wine prefix folder in your home and nothing else. They are closed inside that bottle.

That said it is also true that a default created bottle also creates standard links in to your home folder and root file system, you need to make sure that those are deleted before running the executable. Some pesky trojans will scan drivers for executable or other specific file type and try to infect those.

A better option is to create a new bottle and thus isolating it from your normal bottle, for that you need to run the .exe file on a separate prefix, do that by following this example:

```
export WINEPREFIX=~/wine_possible_trojan
wine winecfg
```

At this point look for the mounted points created for the bottle, they should be on the drives tab, remove any letters that are not `c:\`, that will prevent the trojan of fiddling with any files inside your home or the root file system:

[image]

After removing the drivers from the bottle you can run the executable using the bottle you just created with using something like

```
WINEPREFIX=~/wine_possible_trojan wine path_to_exefile.exe
```

After that deleting `~/wine_possible_trojan` will delete the bottle from your system eliminating the modifications done by the trojan inside that bottle.

If you are unsure you can also install a virus scanner in your Linux system and run that after )and maybe before to see if it picks anything up) deleting the `.wine` prefix. Have a look at this post for options available:

- [Available anti-virus for Ubuntu 11.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79722/what-antivirus-programs-are-available)

---

The other option would be, as [bodhi.zazen](https://askubuntu.com/a/97744/25863) said, to install VirtualBox from the Ubuntu Software Center, install Ubuntu or Windows (if available) in to a new virtual system in VirtualBox and run the .exe inside that virtual system.

For more information about VirtualBox please visit the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox) page, the official [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) page and have a look at [How to install VirtualBox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66765/how-to-install-virtualbox-4-1-4) in AskUbuntu.com.

---

I can see from the AV scan report you added to the comments that only 1 engine picked it up out of all of those on the list, I would say false positive.

Comment: how do I run this in an isolated environment?

Comment: The wine bottle is a sort of isolated environment, delete `~/.wine` and that environment is gone. Other then that do what @bodhi.zazen tells you and run it on a virtualbox system.

Comment: what are some virtualbox applications I can download and run for ubuntu?

Comment: is there any sure shot way that I can make sure that I won't get infected if I run this?

Comment: So its almost similar to a sandbox then?

Comment: hmm... the only thing that is keeping me from doing this is a few double checks with the Wine team.  I've had a similar question like this before and they gave me some different more discomforting answers, I have clamav and did scan with it and nothing came up.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2279/discussion-between-alex-poulos-and-bruno-pereira)

Comment: AFAIK Wine usually has, by default, drive letters set up to point to your home directory and root filesystem. This means the "bottle" you talk about effectively contains your entire home directory plus anything throughout the file system you have permission to access. Maybe this has been changed recently though...?

Comment: @detly no, I don't think so. not entirely sure that if you create a new prefix before running the executable that is also true. thx for the heads up, I will edit the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 11):

You would need to run it in an isolated test system, such as a VM and investigate what it does.

What exactly is it ?

It is hard to believe you "need" to run an infected .exe.

It is possible you have a false positive as well (depending on how you detected the virus and what, if any, investigation you have done).

Comment: Its a program someone made for help with modifying a custom IOS for the Wii. https://www.virustotal.com/file/f9c972b2d60e1ac28563a45f647afee7337f5ff897a51df305b3de2af06da80f/analysis/1327287542/